# Android GPS- initialize once and use it all over the app

Tags: android

In my app, I need fresh gps co-ordinate's in all Activity's. I don't want to initialize the  gps function in all my activity's or don't want to keep static references(as for as my view it is not best practice).

What I need is.

1) initialize the gps function once,and use it all over the app.
     is there any way to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an always running service that tracks the GPS data. Every time onPause is called, it begins 1 minute counter (example) until it disables the GPS monitor. And then onResume would cancel that countdown allowing the GPS data to be maintained or else start listening for GPS locations.

This approach would allow your app to have the same GPS data while not draining the battery excessively (since the GPS would be turned off when app is not in use).

The minute long countdown is only selected since the user might exit your app momentarily then open it again.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the PASSIVE_PROVIDER constant of the LocationManager class : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER

It lets you receive locations that would be retrieved via other providers (GPS, network...) at other places in your application without too much additionnal work on the device.

Comment: actually this is pretty interesting. Have an activity that receives GPS input and then for each activity load a location manager as a Passive_provider. I don't think this is as clean as the answer, but at least this method wouldn't need to fix every time.